# Perforce Merge won't open a file if directory has latin characteres

Tags: p4merge

It's been a while since I last used P4Merge, but last time I checked, there was no such strange issue.
I'm trying to open a file in order to compare it (or merge it) with another file. If I start p4merge.exe, and type a directory like 
"C:\temp\thisFileHere.txt" in any of the boxes (1st or 2nd), it will load it correctly, as expected.

However, if the path contains latin characteres, such as
"C:\temp\ChampsDeElisée.txt", it simply won't open.

Is there a known issue for this?

I'm currently using 2015.1/1233444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, there is an unreported issue.

Downgraded to 2014.1 and it works as expected.